How can I efficiently iterate over a large JSON object in Python to extract specific values?
I'm working with a large JSON object in Python, and I need to extract specific values based on certain keys. Here's a simplified version of the JSON structure:
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Item 1",
        "value": "Value 1"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "attributes": {
        "name": "Item 2",
        "value": "Value 2"
      }
    }
  ]
}


I want to extract the "name" and "value" pairs from each object in the "data" list. What would be the most efficient way to iterate over this JSON object and extract these values?
I've considered using a for loop to iterate over each item, but I'm wondering if there's a more Pythonic or efficient way to do this, especially when dealing with large datasets. Any advice or best practices would be greatly appreciated!
I initially tried using a simple for loop like this:
for item in json_data['data']:
    name = item['attributes']['name']
    value = item['attributes']['value']
    print(f"Name: {name}, Value: {value}")


This works for smaller datasets, but I’m concerned about performance and scalability with larger JSON objects. I was hoping to find a more efficient or Pythonic approach, especially if there are libraries or techniques that can optimize this process. For example, would using pandas or another library be more efficient, or is there a better way to structure the loop for large data?

What is this doing that could be optimized away?  What evidence do you have that this won't be fast enough for you?

See SIMDJson to extract some fields very efficiently (though it is still JSON so not great). If you have a lot of values to extract, then there is no fast solution. Json is not really made for large dataset. Binary file format are (eg. binary dataframes). Pandas is designed to operate on dataframes, not json files. However, if your dataset is large and it can be converted to a binary dataframe, then please consider converting it.

Large JSON datasets is usually a bad design in the first place. Use a database.

The only obvious issue is that you are evaluating item['attributes'] twice; you can write x = item['attributes']; name = x['name']; value = x['value'].

Sounds like premature optimization. Measure and demonstrate that your working solution is insufficient first.

Dump the entire thing in a shelve database. Your optimization will be that you aren't holding the entire thing in memory. You'll almost entirely be able to use dictionary logic and syntax to access it. The only main logical difference will be that you have to open the database (like a file) to manipulate the database. Past that it's basically identical to a dictionary.

If you are going to print every pair, then yes, you have to visit every pair. There is not much you can optimise here. Is your goal really print each pair?

Your code is straightforward and efficient in most cases by using Python’s built-in dictionaries and lists. You can enhance the readability by using the function:
def extract_name_value(data):
    return [(item['attributes']['name'], item['attributes']['value']) for item in data['data']]
result = extract_name_value(json_data)
for name, value in result:
    print(f"Name: {name}, Value: {value}")

For the larger dataset, I would recommend using pandas. Pandas library is helpful for handling structured data. :
import pandas as pd
df = pd.json_normalize(json_data['data'])
result = df[['attributes.name', 'attributes.value']]
name_value_pairs = list(result.itertuples(index=False, name=None))
for name, value in name_value_pairs:
   print(f"Name: {name}, Value: {value}")

